# Cyrillic not appearing

Tags: beamer, babel, cyrillic

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Музика}
Родопската музика е бавна и безмензурна. Обикновено се изпълнява от каба-гайда, тамбура, кавал и тъпан. Гайдата е инструмент с духало, гайдуница, главини, ручило и кожен мях. % \includegraphics{$HOME/Pictures/Images/Bagpipebg.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Other text appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `beamer` uses the sans serif font and if you don't specify it, the standard Latin Modern Sans is used, which has no support for Cyrillic.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Музика}
Родопската музика е бавна и безмензурна. Обикновено се изпълнява от каба-гайда, 
тамбура, кавал и тъпан. Гайдата е инструмент с духало, гайдуница, главини, ручило 
и кожен мях. % \includegraphics{$HOME/Pictures/Images/Bagpipebg.png}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]